# the text white color doesn't appear... what's wrong in my code?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

[nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrvPY.png)
[html code]

```
<div class="navigation">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Gallery</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <div>
            <a
              href="#"
              class="py-2 px-6 rounded-full bg-slate-900 hover:bg-orange-700 text-white"
              >Call US</a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
```

[components]

```
.navigation {
  @apply hidden md:flex space-x-6;
}

.navigation a {
  @apply text-slate-900 hover:text-orange-700;
}
```

when i change anything in the code the word (call us) appears and this styling goes [the styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M61po.png)

Comment: Can you add html also. ?

Comment: Are you using any other library?? text-white should work. What is the current color of text?

Comment: It is working fine. I tested that. Did you add any other library to the page??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text on the "Call Us" button to be white, you need to remove the `text-slate-900` from the `.navigation a`, as the class selector combined with the element selector has a higher specificity than the single class selector used by `text-white`.

```css
.navigation a {
  @apply hover:text-orange-700;
}
```

You can check on Tailwind playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/v0tJaJEAVU?file=css

Comment: thank you so much, it needs after I remove the text-slate-900 from the .navigation a to run (npm run watch in terminal).